# Trying to catch System.Net.WebException (C#) in Java

Tags: c#, java, web-services, exception, network-protocols

What is the closest equivalent of `System.Net.WebException` in Java?

I am trying to do this in Java. The program is polling for new statuses and messages in a while true loop, but if the network "hiccups" for a second, I want to catch the exception.

```
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                GetStatusChanges();
                GetReturnMessages();
                if (pollCounter == 30)
                {
                    SubmitMessages();
                    pollCounter = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException webException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(webException);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            pollCounter++;
        }
```

Looking in the java.net package, I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: What is a "hiccup"? Do you have some Java code already? I'm pretty sure what you want is IOException or SocketException.

Comment: Did my answer help you? You might want to accept it, if so. If not, tell me why not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is java.net.SocketException, or its descendants, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106810/catching-exceptions-caused-by-temporary-network-errors) question.

I have found that some other cases might throw other [IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) subclasses, like [UnknownServiceException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/UnknownServiceException.html) (SocketException is also a subclass of IOException.)

Comment: Just started learning java yesterday from working with C#. I thought there would be one with a similar name, since `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` also exists in .NET; but the description sounds about right.

Comment: I have found that other types of IOException might occur. Extended my answer. You might want to familiarize yourself with the Java documentation. For example here is the Exception class documetnation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html